# Alder Lake graphics driver in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics

How can I get Alder Lake graphics drivers? I'm running 20.04 with the HWE-edge kernel (5.13), but I'm not able to use the igpu for hardware acceleration.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:46000000-46ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:48000000-4effffff
```

With other new unsupported hardware (like a 2.5GBE) I've been able to download drivers from the manufacturer's website. Does nothing like this exist for intel?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are trying to use hardware acceleration and how you know that it's not working?  Are you using Ubuntu Desktop or any desktop environment?  If your only graphics adapter is the iGPU and you are running a desktop environment, then it's working.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu server, and I'd like to use the iGPU for plex hw transcoding. The igpu isn't detected, and like other hw without drivers, it is shown as UNCLAIMED with the lshw command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the HWE-edge kernel was updated to 5.15 and included the intel drivers. You can see that now the i915 driver is shown with `sudo lshw -c display`.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:144 memory:46000000-46ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:48000000-4effffff
```